# Web Application Build and Deployment Strategies

Tags: asp.net, svn, msbuild

We have a web application and occasionally a bug will creep up that needs to be taken care of and fixed. We are using subversion as our code repository. What I am wrestling with is at what point do you create a new branch or tag. We were thinking that if the application needed to be rebuilt or the MSI needed to be rebuilt then we would create a branch. In the case of something simple like a typo, we would just distribute out the offending .aspx page.

What are some of your strategies for branching and building strategies?

Currently, ours looks like this. We have a class library, and Web application. We make our corrections, copy over the changed pages/DLLs to the MSI Creator (Advanced Installer) then rebuild our MSI. We are debating on whether or not to use a web deployment project/MSbuild or something similar. We need it to be reproducible, reliable and simple.

Comment: Do you have a CI machine/environment? (CI = Continuous Integration)

Comment: Currently, we do not have any continuous integration servers set up. I had used CC.net in the past, about 4-5 years ago, with mixed results.

Comment: Give CC.NET another try.  with this caveat.  write 99% of your build logic in a msbuild definition file (.proj), use CC.NET to download the code from svn, then use cc.net to call "msbuild.exe MyMsBuild.proj"......it's worth the effort to get there.  by putting 99% of the logic in the proj file, you future safe yourself if you move away from CC.NET.

Answer (score 0):

When you release your code, you would "tag" it.  Let's say you tag it with "ReleaseVersion_1.2.3.4"

The "trunk" would be your main branch.  And you continue to develop there.

If a bug comes along for a customer who has the released code, you would branch from the "tag" ( "ReleaseVersion_1.2.3.4" ), and would hotfix something there.

Then you would most likely merge code from this HotFix back to "trunk".

That's the simplest way.

There are many options for branch strategies.

But if your code hotfixes are occasional, this one will work.

Comment: I think what we have decided to do is at a particular date as, freeze development. This will then be a "read-only" version of our project. We will then create a Maintenance branch. This will be where bugs are fixed. We are a small three-man shop and do not do much merging or patching as it just becomes a headache

Comment: Dude......"tagging" your code is like....2 mouse clicks....... just because you're small and only do merging on occasion...that doesn't mean skip some basic steps.  making a "tag" is pretty simple....and you get one moment in time to do it.  It doesn't hurt anything if you don't use it.